# Adding default values in JQuery jTable add/edit forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using JQuery jTable plugin in my web application. I have to set some fields in the add/edit form of jTable while loading the form. There is a callback for getting control while creating the form.

```
formCreated: function (event, data) 
{

}
```

I can access the input elements also through

```
data.form.find('input[name="Name"]')
```

But, How will I set some default value in these input elements??

Comment: This is how I solved it:  $(data.form.find('input[name="Name"]')).val("Value")

Answer (score 2):

Use defaultValue propert of jTable. See documantation: http://jtable.org/ApiReference#fopt-defaultValue

Comment: is it possible to segment my form with custom titles? Great work with jtable

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a good way to do it as told by hikalkan. But if you want to set another input controls value to input element in form, use following in formCreated event:->

```
$("Edit-(your input control's id)").val($("#(controls id which is outside the form)").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Both other answers have typos.  So building on both answers from @hikalkan and @Shekhar here is a summary.

For static default values use the defaulValue property and set to either a value or the value of another element.  To hide the property from the user forms use set the type property to 'hidden'.

For dynamic elements use the formCreated event to snap the current state of the page.

```
$('#jtable_main').jtable({
  field_static: {
    defaultValue: 2,
  },
  field_depends: {
    type: 'hidden',
    defaultValue: $('#base_id').val(),
  },
  field_dynamic: {
    type: 'hidden',
    // defaultValue: // set in formCreated
  },
  formCreated: function(event, data) {
    $('#Edit-field_dynamic').val($('#base_id').val());
  },
});
```